# Can Virtual Box/VMware infect the host PC when testing Cryptolocker?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, malware

Can cryptolocker encrypt the host PC if I test it on a Virtual Machine?

Currently I am using 'NAT' as my network type or whatever...

Comment: I would Run the VMware Virtual drive inside a Sandbox then you should be fine. If it infects the Sandbox you can just delete it. Make sure you do not bridge your network with the Virtual box as it may try to get your system too. But the sandbox should keep it contained from what I have read so Install [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?DownloadSandboxie) and right click your vmware and start it in there make sure you make a sandbox just for your vmware that way you can delete it when done if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

**Be aware that [CryptoLocker will encrypt any files it finds on network shares](https://www.infopackets.com/news/9507/can-cryptolocker-infect-shared-drives-files-pcs).** Therefore, you should remove all virtual network cards from your virtual machine. (Don't just disable them within the guest operating system as this runs the risk of them being re-enabled by malicious software. I doubt cryptolocker does this, but it is still good security hygiene. Also, don't simply disable the networking on your host machine as this could still allow the guest to communicate with the host over the loopback adapter.)

Also, ensure that any hardware passthrough support of any kind is disabled in your Virtual Machine software. This may include

- USB support
- raw disk access
- shared folders
- VT-D/AMD-V passthrough
- serial passthrough

More generally, if you are interested in investigating the behavior of malicious software, there are at least a couple of extra things you should be aware of.

1. Given the complexity of modern VM software, it is reasonable to assume that all VM software on the market has exploitable bugs which would allow malicious software running on the guest to compromise the host OS. My understanding is that it is relatively uncommon for malicious software to do this, but if you want to be as safe as possible, you should install the VM on a completely separate PC that has no important data, no network/wifi cards, and is only used for investigating malicious software.
2. A lot of malicious software these days can tell whether it is being run in common VM environments and refuse to run or alter its behavior under these circumstances.

Disclaimer: Everyone should critically evaluate any security advice they receive. I make no claim that this advice is correct/complete, nor do I claim that acting based on it won't go horribly wrong. Anyone using it should use it at their own risk.

Answer (score 0):

No - it can only encrypt files it can access - so provided it can't see any files outside the container its in, it can't harm the host OS directly.